# Submitting URL to iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, submission

Using iTunes Connect, I'm trying to upload my first app, and there is a field on the upload page that asks for a URL to your website. I don't have a website to give them, what do I do?

Is there any way to pass the URL field?

Comment: I've seen things like email addresses in that field, but it's probably best if you set yourself up a free website, somewhere like here: sites.google.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out http://app.net/; it's exactly what you need!